# Trigger Auto-Repeat Javascript keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyevent, autorepeat

When you hold down a key, the javascript `keydown` event is triggered repeatedly while the key is still down. I want to programmatically simulate this effect. I have tried the following code but it only triggers the `keydown` event only once:

```
e = jQuery.Event("keydown"); // define this once in global scope
e.which = 38; // Some key value
$("input").trigger(e);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should call .trigger() every 50 ms forever...

```
e = jQuery.Event("keydown"); // define this once in global scope
e.which = 38; // Some key value

setInterval(function() {
  $("input").trigger(e);
}, 50); // Change 50 to whatever you like.
```